# how x y and z become equal in this solution?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand an example given in my book but not able to understand it as I am quite weak in mathematics. 
In the below images I don't get how x, y and z become equal to each other. Please help!
[image: Image 1]

[image: image2]

Comment: it is a condition,"at x=y=z"

Comment: I think they simply don't. It seems to me that you're just tasked to verify that a certain partial derivative is equal to something when you evaluate it on $\{x=t\wedge y=t\wedge z=t\}$.

Comment: = show that when

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that **at** $x=y=z$, the derivative is what it is. That means you need to prove the statement

> If $x=y=z$, then $\frac{\partial d^2z}{\partial x\partial y} = ...$

And any time you prove a statement of the type "If $A$, then $B$", you do it by assuming $A$ is true and, from that, proving that $B$ is true.

Comment: can you please explain me this

Comment: @user3788135 I just did. What part of the explanation is unclear to you?